# How to structure celery tasks

Tags: python, celery

I have 2 types of task: async tasks and schedule tasks. So, here is my dir structure:

```
proj
  |
  -- tasks
      |
      -- __init__.py
      |
      -- celeryapp.py     => celery instance defined in this file.
      |
      -- celeryconfig.py
      |
      -- async
      |    |
      |    -- __init__.py
      |    |
      |    -- task1.py    => from proj.tasks.celeryapp import celery
      |    |
      |    -- task2.py    => from proj.tasks.celeryapp import celery
      |
      -- schedule
           |
           -- __init__.py
           |
           -- task1.py    => from proj.tasks.celeryapp import celery
           |
           -- task2.py    => from proj.tasks.celeryapp import celery
```

But when I run celery worker like below, it does not work. It can not accept the task from celery beat scheduler.

```
 $ celery worker --app=tasks -Q my_queue,default_queue
```

So, is there any best practice on multiple task files organization?

Comment: Have you tried adding `-B` to the command? It should execute `celerybeat`

Comment: BTW, is it a `django` project?

Comment: Asking about "how to structure celery tasks" is irrelevant/premature unless you *know* that your file layout is the cause of things not working.

Also, please provide more detail on what "it does not work" and "cannot accept the task from celerybeat" mean. 

In other words, what do you expect to happen, and what happens instead? Specifically. Share error output.

Answer (score 12):

Based on celery [documentation](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/_modules/celery/app/base.html#Celery.autodiscover_tasks) you can import a structure of celery tasks like this:

For example if you have an (imagined) directory tree like this:

```
|
|-- foo
|    |-- __init__.py
|    |-- tasks.py
|
|-- bar
     |-- __init__.py
     |-- tasks.py
```

Then calling `app.autodiscover_tasks(['foo', bar'])` will result in the modules foo.tasks and bar.tasks being imported.

Answer (score 3):

Celery tasks can be async, sync or scheduled depends on its invocation

```
task.delay(arg1,arg2)       #will be async
task.delay(arg1,arg2).get() #will be sync
task.delay(arg1,arg2).get() #will be sync
task.apply_async(args = [arg1,arg2], {'countdown' : some_seconds}) #async with delay
```

There's a lot of invocations depending on your needs
However, you must start celery with -B flag to enable celery scheduler

```
$ celery worker --app=tasks -B -Q my_queue,default_queue
```

So the way you take to organize your tasks is something personal and it deppends on your project complexity, but I think that organize them by its type of synchronism wouldn't be the best option.
I've googled this topic and I haven't found any guide or advise, but I've read some cases that organize their task by their functionality. 
I've followed this advise, because this isn't a pattern, in my projects. Here one example of how I did

```
your_app
    |
    -- reports
        |
        -- __init__.py
        -- foo_report.py
        -- bar_report.py
        -- tasks
            |
            -- __init__.py
            -- report_task.py
    -- maintenance
        |
        -- __init__.py
        -- tasks
            |
            -- __init__.py
            -- delete_old_stuff_task.py
    -- twitter
        |
        -- __init__.py
        -- tasks
            |
            -- __init__.py
            -- batch_timeline.py
```

Comment: This doesn't actually answer anything?

Comment: it was fine. Wish there was some explanation and examples on how the tasks were executed with this file structure.