# unable to import celery app in task files

Tags: python, import, celery

I have the following folder structure

```
git_repo_main
   └───my_sub_project
       │   celery_app.py
       │   __init__.py
       │
       ├───calcs
       │   │   math_funcs.py  -> from my_sub_project.celery_app import app
       │   │   __init__.py
       │
       ├───piplines
           │   run_math_pipeline.py -> from my_sub_project.calcs import math_funcs
           │   __init__.py
```

with `celery_app.py` looking like this:

```
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('my_sub_project',
             broker='amqp://guest@localhost//',
             backend='amqp://guest@localhost//',
             include=['calculations.math_funcs']
             )
```

I also have the code at my [repo](https://github.com/MosheVai/project_celery_exp)

when running celery using this command: `celery -A celery_app worker -l info -P gevent`,  I am getting the following error

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'my_sub_project'
```

full error [stack](https://pastebin.com/ERN4SNDy) for `app` import

what would be a solution?

---

I have read the documentation for the [naming and imports](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#automatic-naming-and-relative-imports), however changing 
the imports to include `git_repo_main` produces the same error, plus it's my source root so its counter to the default import structure of most IDE's.

I also have found a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702578/how-to-structure-celery-tasks) , however it seems to address a problem of task discovery and not `app` and tasks imports.

**Note**: I am not using django

Comment: What if you use `app = Celery('.', …)`?

Comment: @mkrieger1 it produces the same error

Comment: What if `celery_app.py` is moved one level up to `git_repo_main`?

Comment: Can you please include the full stack trace of the error message?

Comment: @mkrieger1 its seems to solve the app import error, however now when i run `run_math_pipeline` the tasks in `math_funcs` are not registered.

Comment: @mkrieger1 added the stack, also moving celery_app.py is not describable because other sub projects have their own celery apps

Comment: create `__init__.py` at `my_sub_project` dir and try again.

Answer (score 0):

Run your Celery worker in the `git_repo_main` directory with PYTHONPATH specified. Something like: `PYTHONPATH=. celery -A celery_app.app worker -l info -P gevent`